# Is this list comparison in Python unnecessary?

Tags: python, list, list-comparison

The [Count and Compare Anagram solution](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/AlgorithmAnalysis/AnAnagramDetectionExample.html#solution-4-count-and-compare) provided at [interactivepython.org](http://interactivepython.org) checks iterates through the lists for a final time checking if the count for each ASCII value is the same.

```
j = 0
stillOK = True
while j<26 and stillOK:
    if c1[j]==c2[j]:
        j = j + 1
    else:
        stillOK = False

return stillOK
```

Why not use the comparison operator?

```
return (c1 == c2)
```

Full code:

```
def anagramSolution4(s1,s2):
    c1 = [0]*26
    c2 = [0]*26

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        pos = ord(s1[i])-ord('a')
        c1[pos] = c1[pos] + 1

    for i in range(len(s2)):
        pos = ord(s2[i])-ord('a')
        c2[pos] = c2[pos] + 1

    j = 0
    stillOK = True
    while j<26 and stillOK:
        if c1[j]==c2[j]:
            j = j + 1
        else:
            stillOK = False

    return stillOK

print(anagramSolution4('apple','pleap'))
```

Edited to add:

I've tested with:

```
anagramSolution4('abc','cba') #returns True
anagramSolution4('abc','cbd') #returns False
anagramSolution4('abc','cbah') #returns False
```

..they all pass. What would be an appropriate test to show c1==c2 fails?

Comment: Why don't you just try the code and find out if it works?

Comment: Yes it's necessary, because there is no comparison made between the inputs without this loop... there's better ways to do the entire thing but that loop is currently necessary.

Comment: @MattDMo I did, and it passed tests `anagramSolution4('abc','cba')` and `anagramSolution4('abc','cbd')` and `anagramSolution4('abc','cbah')`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but there is a much easier way to implement this using `collections.Counter`, a generator expression, and string methods.  First make a helper function `def letter_counts(s):return Counter(c.lower() for c in s if c.isalpha())` then compare `letter_counts(s1) == letter_counts(s2)`.  You can leave out the helper function if you are only comparing lowercase words with no punctuation or spaces:  `Counter(s1) == Counter(s2)`.

Comment: Likewise, solution 2 could be reimplemented as `sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)`.  I suspect that point of this verbose code is to make all the steps clear to beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `==` on the two lists would produce the same result, but would also hide some implementation details. Given that the script comes from a website used for learning, I guess this is for learning purposes.

Also, I see that in the webpage you are asked some questions about complexities. Well, using `c1 == c2` instead of the loop would probably mislead some people and make them think that the operation is O(1) instead of O(min(len(c1), len(c2)))<sup>[1]</sup>.

Finally, note that there are many languages which have no notion of lists.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> This isn't necessarily true either, as the two lists may contain items with custom and complex `__eq__()` methods.